# ¿Se pueden devolver varios valores con un return? c#

Tags: c#

Quiero devolver dos valores para no tener que volver a escribir el  mismo código pero enviando los valores por separados ya que no quiero que se cambie el valor de la fila si el saldo es menor a 0 pero me marca error

```
public DataRow bool row(DataTable tabla,int retiro)
    {
        bool comp = false;
        foreach (DataRow row in tabla.Rows)
        {
            if (cliente == row["Cliente"].ToString()) 
            {
                if ((saldo = saldo - retiro - cargoTransaccion) < 0)
                {
                    comp = true;
                    row["Saldo"] = saldo;
                    return (comp,row);
                }
                else
                    comp = false;
            }
        }
        return comp;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Y cual otro valor ademas de `comp` deseas devolver?

Comment: Si se cumple la condición, mandar comp y row para que en el form mande row y lo añade a un datatable y si el comp=true no mande mensaje diciendo que saldo no puede ser saldo<0 ,si no se cumple solo manda comp y en el form manda el mensaje

Comment: En tu código  realmente mandas true siempre cuando actualizas la  tabla o se  cumple la condición y para los otros casos false. En  ese sentido no  necesitas del bool sólo retorna nulo o el row. Si  el row!=null es como si te hubieras recibido el  true,y row==null es como si hubiera devuelto false. Total igual vas a cambiar el valor  de retorno de  la  función.

Comment: También puedes utilizar [Tuplas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples)

Comment: @PabloGutiérrez deberías añadir una respuesta con un ejemplo de retornar una tupla. Es un método muy interesante y me gustaría verlo como una respuesta para futuros usuarios :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En atención a la sugerencia de @Pikoh, ampliaré mi comentario relacionado con las [Tuplas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) en una respuesta.

> Las tuplas proporcionan una sintaxis concisa para agrupar varios elementos de datos en una estructura ligera.

En términos simples, una tupla es una lista de elementos de cualquier tipo separados por coma y encerrada entre paréntesis.

Si observamos el código publicado en la pregunta, la línea `return (comp,row);` en realidad estaría retornando una tupla.

Así que con unas pocas correcciones, el método de la pregunta quedaría listo para cumplir el requerimiento utilizando tuplas.

```
//     La lista de tipos de retorno va entre paréntesis
//     y separada por coma
//     |       |     |
//     V       V     V
public (DataRow, bool) row(DataTable tabla,int retiro)
{
    bool comp = false;
    foreach (DataRow row in tabla.Rows)
    {
        if (cliente == row["Cliente"].ToString()) 
        {
            if ((saldo = saldo - retiro - cargoTransaccion) < 0)
            {
                comp = true;
                row["Saldo"] = saldo;


                //      | Invierte el orden de los datos devueltos
                //      | para hacerlos coincidir con la declaracion del método.
                //      | Primero DataRow y después bool
                //      V
                return (row, comp);
            }
            else
                comp = false;
        }
    }

    //      | Corrige este return para devolver la tupla
    //      V
    return (null, comp);
}
```

Ahora que el método no tiene errores de compilación, lo puedes utilizar de la siguiente manera:

```
     //  Esta es una de varias formas de declarar la tupla que recibirás.
     //  Cada elemento con su tipo y el nombre de variable que queremos utilizar
     //  _____________________^_____________________
     // |                                           |
        (DataRow filaActualizada, bool retiroExitoso) = row(dataTable, 100);

        if(retiroExitoso)
        {
            // código para un retiro efectuado con exito
            // aqui seguramente se hace algo con el otro valor
            // de la tupla en la variable filaActualizada
        }
        else
        {
            // código cuando el retiro no pudo ejecutarse
        }
```

---

**Actualización:**
*Gracias a la sugerencia de @gbianchi, extiendo un poco la explicación del llamado a métodos que devuelven Tuplas y asignación entre tipos de Tuplas.*

---

Para almacenar el resultado de métodos que devuelven tuplas, podemos declarar variables de la siguiente manera:

- `(DataRow, bool) resultado = MetodoQueDevuelveTupla();`  Al utilizar esta declaración, cada elemento de la tupla será nombrado como `Item1`,`Item2` por el compilador y para hacer referencia a ellos utilizamos `resultado.Item1` *(este sería el `DataRow`)* o `resultado.Item2` *(este sería el `bool`)*
- `(DataRow FilaActualizada, bool RetiroExitoso) resultado = MetodoQueDevuelveTupla();` Con esta declaración decidimos el nombre que tendrá cada elemento de la tupla y podemos hacer referencia a ellos de la siguiente manera `resultado.FilaActualizada` o `resultado.RetiroExitoso`
- `(DataRow filaActualizada, bool retiroExitoso) = MetodoQueDevuelveTupla()` Aunque esta declaración parece igual que la anterior, la principal diferencia es que, en esta, cada elemento de la tupla es asignado a una variable individual. Esto es lo que se conoce como *deconstrucción de tuplas* y es la sintaxis que utilicé en mi ejemplo anterior.
- Existen otras formas de declarar tuplas que pueden ser exploradas en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples).

##### Notas:

La intención de esta respuesta es ofrecer otra posible solución utilizando Tuplas y solamente abarca una pequeña parte de un tema algo extenso. La [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) es un buen punto de partida para conocer más detalles.

De acuerdo con lo que entedí del texto de la pregunta, me parece que la condición `if ((saldo = saldo - retiro - cargoTransaccion) < 0)` hace exactamente lo contrario, actualiza la fila cuando el Saldo es menor que cero. Creo que la comparación debería ser `>= 0`.

Como comentario final, recomiendo utilizar nombres que aporten un significado acorde a la acción que realizan o al dato que contienen. Por ejemplo:

- Un método llamado `row` no contribuye en nada a entender su propósito, `IntentarRetiro` o `Retiro` pudieran ofrecer un mejor significado.
- Lo mismo aplica para la variable `cont`.

Comment: ah cierto.. se me confudio el comentario o por lo menos no me quedo claro de entrada.. ojo con eso...

Comment: @gbianchi, Gracias por la observación, acabo de publicar una actualización con un poco más de detalles en la declaración de las Tuplas.

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Gracias por aportarla a la comunidad :)

Answer (score 4):

Una solución adicional a la que ya te expusieron en la respuesta de Francisco Núñez, es pasar un argumento con el atributo `out` es decir un parametro de salida, al que le asiginas el valor dentro del procedimiento y luego puedes recuperar su valor.

```
public bool Retiros(DataTable tabla,int retiro, out DataRow rowSalida)
{
    bool comp = false;
    rowSalida = null;
    foreach (DataRow row in tabla.Rows)
    {
      if (cliente == row["Cliente"].ToString()) 
      {
        if ((saldo = saldo - retiro - cargoTransaccion) < 0)
        {
          comp = true;
          row["Saldo"] = saldo;
          rowSalida = row;
          return comp;
        }
        else
           comp = false;
       }
     }
 return comp;
```

}

En el caso de que no se cumpla la condición, wel valor de la fila devuelta es nulo, pero evitas manejarla lo que generaria un error, haciendo una condicional `if` teniendo en cuanta que en ese caso el procedimeitno devuelve false.
Para referenciar o llamar al metodo debe hacerse lo siguiente.

```
DataTable tablaOrg;
int valorRetiro = 100;
if(Retiros(tablaOrg,valorRetiro , out DataRow RowSalida)
{
   //Agregar el codigo de lo que desees hacer con la variable RowSalida 

}
else
{
  MessageBox.Show("El valor del retiro es mayor que el saldo disponible");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes retornar un arreglo:

```
string[] str = new string[5];
str[0] = "My";
str[1] = "name";
return str;
```

Luego cuando lo recibes deberías hacer esto:

```
var arrayDatos = MultipleReturns();
var tuvariable1 = arrayDatos[0];
var tuvariable2 = arrayDatos[1];
```

de esta manera los cambios son mínimos ...

puedes profundizar mas con la lista de formas en que se puede retornar múltiples datos, aquí te dejo la documentación:

**Incluye:**

- Parámetros de referencia
- Parámetros de salida
- Devolver una matriz
- Devolver un objeto de tipo clase / estructura
- Devolver una tupla

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9b86d4/how-to-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: Gracias, lo intentare